# Can local notifications download information from the web swift

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Right now I have local notifications setup to send the user a notification, by default at 9, about the weather. But its not getting the most recent weather, its getting the weather from the last time the user refresh the weather. So it has no purpose, is there a way to download the information just before I send the user a notification? If not could you help me with setting up push notification, is there an easy way? I have a server and I could use that but I don't know where to start.

Comment: This is a good push notification tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Comment: No, a local notification can't download anything, a notification is not a little piece of executable code. You are on the right track thinking about push notifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with local notifications, but so-called silent push notifications might work in this case. If you use the [`content-available`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1) property in your notification, you can implement the [`application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:) method in your application delegate, which reacts on this and retrieves the latest weather from your server. Of course, these notifications are *silent*, so you need a separate notification (either local or remote) to alert the user.